# Cisco ASA 5505 System Reload (reboot/restart)

Tags: c#, java, cisco

I have a Cisco ASA 5505 and I need to reboot it daily (it is lagging).

Could anyone suggest some method / code on how can I reboot it without logging on to console or manually resetting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an API for this device, maybe you can send some reboot request that way. If not, there are java libraries for ssh and there are open source ssh clients. It probably wouldn't take long to write a small java program to ssh in and then issue a reload command. You can schedule this little java program to run every day using your OS or some task scheduling software.